# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) despite granted privileges

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I can access mysql from the command line, and can also access via phpmyadmin. I've granted all privileges both via command line and via phpmyadmin but when i try to access locally, it runs the same access denied.

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost|
+----------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'HASHED' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `table`.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                                                                                                                                |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I realise this question has been asked multiple times but all solutions provided thus far have come up fruitless. Any help will be hugely appreciated, because I have to commit my code and pull it to a server every time I want to make a change to the db (which gives an embarrassing amount of commits).

EDIT (to clarify): This error only happens whenever I have to do something on my local development machine. Whenever I try and run artisan migrate, or login to the authentication system I've integrated into my app.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? In what scenario do you receive this error message?  You mention you can access it through the command line, and through phpMyAdmin, so what does 'access it locally' mean?

Comment: @Redbeard011010 I'm using Laravel so whenever I try and run a migration it comes up. I've also added basic authentication and when I try and login 'locally'  (i.e on my local development machine). Basically, anything offline throws the error.

Comment: Do you have set your config.php (or .env file) to point to the database correctly?

Comment: @Franco yes, migrations run on the server just not on the development machine.

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.46, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2 if this helps.

Comment: So, let's clarify... when you're getting this message, are you trying to connect to a MySQL server running on the same machine, or on a different machine?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot MYSQL server is running on a different machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this issue arose but I had to change my config.inc.php file to include the MySQL username and password. I think it must have been an issue with the installation of MySQL. The file is located MAMP\bin\phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Please,check up a "--skip-name-resolve" variable value.  Is it "On" or "Off" ?
  You may do it from mysql command promt>: show variables like '%skip%';

Comment: skip name resolve is off as is skip networking (which I think may also be problematic). Not sure how to resolve?

Comment: Lets check up password length 16 bytes or 41 bytes(table mysql.user) and what value "secure_auth" variable has?

Comment: secure_auth is off, password length i'm not sure

Comment: ok. 1. use the command > desc mysql.user; check  up a password field length. Is it char(16) or char(41)?

Comment: 2. What is the length of hashed password?

Comment: password length is char(41)

Comment: Sorry, can't imagine what is it.

Comment: well, let's see what in mysql.user table. could you execute this statement:  
select host,user from mysql.user;  
 What's the result?

Comment: and execute this statement when you are connected to mysql    serverfrom command line and mysqladmin:  
select current_user();  
Whar are the results;